# c# Dictionary<string, List<Data>> data to csv or excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv, dictionary, listobject

I have a `Dictionary<string, List<Data>>`   in the form of data. Here, with the help of my string keyword, I want to access the data I have stored in the `List<Data>` and convert it to excel or csv format.

```
*******************************
**            KEY            **
*******************************
** StringData ** IntegerData **
**  ''        ** ''          **
**  ''        ** ''          **
**  ''        ** ''          **
```

I want to create a table structure on an excel csv like the one above.

```
 public struct Data
        {
            public Data(String strValue, int intValue)
            {
                IntegerData = intValue;
                StringData = strValue;
            }

            public int IntegerData { get; private set; }
            public string StringData { get; private set; }
        }

 Dictionary<string, List<Data>> ds = new Dictionary<string, List<Data>>();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many references about storing data from C# to csv/excel

Comment: @GiladGreen. Yes I tried but I could not get the data in List <Data> and I could not create the table like the above structure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206279/exporting-the-values-in-list-to-excel very similar question

Comment: You can use a tool such as [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/3.0.0-chi06)