# C# - How to insert bulk data in Excel via Microsoft Office Interop Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop, bulkinsert

I am currently using Microsoft's **Microsoft Office Interop Excel** in order to insert 28k row into an Excel file.

It should look like this (with 28k rows instead of 31):

[image]

I am inserting the data in the following foreach loop:

```
foreach (var displayableProduct in DisplayableMATProductList)
        {
            Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.MATProduct.MATProductNumber;
            column++;
            if (displayableProduct.MATProduct.tblFormat != null) Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.MATProduct.tblFormat.FormatName;
            column++;
            if (displayableProduct.MATProduct.tblGrade != null) Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.MATProduct.tblGrade.GradeName;
            column++;
            if (displayableProduct.MATProduct.tblProduct != null) Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.MATProduct.tblProduct.ProductCASNumber;
            column++;
            Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.ProductInflammabilityLevel;
            column++;
            Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.ProductToxicityLevel;
            column++;
            Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.ProductReactivityLevel;
            column++;
            Worksheet.Cells[row, column] = displayableProduct.ProductSpecialLevel;
            column++;

            row++;
            column = 1;
        }
```

However, the problem is that the operation is taking about 10 minutes.

Does anyone know a faster way to insert bulk data into an Excel Worksheet?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206279/exporting-the-values-in-list-to-excel

Comment: [How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel)

Comment: Ok, great. Did you guys personally try any of these methods? If so, which one is your favourite for working with a large quantity of data?