# C# How to use list from JsonConvert DeserializeObject to insert values into Excel

Tags: c#, json, list, json-deserialization

I make an API call and deserialize the JSON response. JSON response shown below. I want to take the values from Test1 and add those to a list to then insert into an Excel worksheet.

```
...

public class Loc
{
    public string Area1 { get; set; }
    public string Area2 { get; set; }
}

public class Risk
{
    public float Test1 { get; set; }
    public float Test2 { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Loc loc;
    public Risk risk;
}


[
  {
    "Loc": {
      "Area1": "1",
      "Area2": "2"
    },
    "Risk": {
      "Test1": 1.14,
      "Test2": 1.72
    }
  },
  {
    "Loc": {
      "Area3": "3",
      "Area4": "4"
    },
    "Risk": {
      "Test1": 1.14,
      "Test2": 1.71
    }
  }
]
var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(apiResult);
```

When I loop through the deserialized object I can access the values for Test1 and write to the console. But when I loop through and access the same values to add to a list (see below) and loop through that list to see the results I get `ConsoleApp.Program+Score`. I'm not sure how to use what I have added to my list - meaning can I access this list to insert data into an Excel worksheet?

```
foreach (var data in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.Risk.Test1);
}

public class Score
{
    public float score { get; set; }
}

List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();

foreach (var score in records)
{
    scores.Add(new Score
    {
        score = score.risk.Test1
    });
}

foreach (object s in scores)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: B3cause s is an object and you can't print the object itself. You can serialize and print the string that way or you can specifically print the score.risk.Test1

Comment: @Jawad Thank you. I essentially want to add the Test1 values 1.14, 1.15 etc to a list which I would then insert into an Excel worksheet. I'm not sure what I do actually have in my list and whether that's possible.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where you are stuck.  Is your only problem that you are unable to print your `object s` to the console?  If so, see maybe [C#: Printing all properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/852181) and [What is the best way to dump entire objects to a log in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/360277).  Or you could [override the `ToString()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18200427) of `Score` to print the desired content.

Comment: If those questions don't answer yours, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: @dbc sorry. I have amended the question to hopefully be clearer. I essentially want to take the values from my list for Test1 and insert those into an Excel worksheet. I'm just not sure how I can do that from the list I have created. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the `Response` class

Comment: @stuartd have added the ```Response``` class to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @CGarden - If your real question is, *How can I export a list of values to Excel*, then all the JSON stuff is somewhat irrelevant, isn't it?  How are you thinking to export to Excel?  Via a CSV file?  Via Excel Interop?  Something else?

Comment: For Excel interop, see maybe [Exporting the values in List to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2206279).  Or if you prefer to export via CSV use the [tag:csvhelper] package.  See e.g. [Are there any CSV readers/writer libraries in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094885/3744182) or [Writing a CSV file in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1684667/3744182).

Comment: Thanks. I referenced the JSON to show how I had got the data and I didn't know if I had populated the list correctly from the deserialization I just thought getting the data into a list and working with it would be a good start. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Instead of using List of Score... why not use List of string/double? That might help get just the lost of values

Comment: @Jawad thank you. Can you create a list of string and double? Sorry I think I see what you mean.

Comment: Since your values are float, list of float

Comment: @Jawad yes that has worked thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re Jawad's comment thank you. Changed the list I was populating to float and added the Test1 values, instead of what I was doing which was adding the whole object to the list.

Amended:

```
public class Score
{
    public float score { get; set; }
}

List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();

foreach (var score in records)
{
    scores.Add(new Score
    {
        score = score.risk.Test1
    });
}
```

To:

```
List<float> scores = new List<float>();

foreach (var score in records)
{
    scores.Add(score.risk.Test1);
}
```